# MS Graph API - Patching Group Event Description does not send update to Attendees

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, ms-office, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api, outlook-api

I am updating a group calendar event using Graph API.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/events/{event-id}
```

- When I update the start or end date the update is correctly send to
  all attendees.
- When I only update the description of the event, the
  update is not sent to the attendees.
- The organizer (a group) gets the update in his inbox.
- The attendee (also an O365 group) does not get the update in his inbox.
- When I update the location, the update also gets send to all attendees.

What is the issue here?

My current workaround is, to generate a random number which I pass as location - as fortunately, I don't need the location field in the event. But I might need it in the future and thats the most stupid workaround ever.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the description of the event"? Which property is `description`? And please share the full request (including the request body) of updating description.

Comment: As requested by Allen, can you please get us more information on this? So that we can help

Comment: As this was some time ago. I figured that this seems to be expected behavior for Calendars. An update will only be send when changing the location or date-time of an event. It is expected behavior that no update is sent when the description (property: "body/content") is updated. My workaround is: I am generating a random integer number, which I put into the location of the event. As the location changes the update is sent to all invited personas. Though, it is a shitty work-around, but I did not find a way to send the update to the attendees in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the comment here so that the question can be treated as answered.

You are right. The update of `body/content` won't be sent to the O365 group attendee.

Attendee who is a user or shared mailbox will receive the update of `body/content`.

However, as this requirement is reasonable, you could post your idea in [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).